# R json key and value

Tags: r, rstudio

Currently i have a data frame that looks something like this

```
client  details
    4   {"A": 1, "B": 2}
    4   {"A": 3, "B": 4}
    4   {"A": 0}
    5   {"C": -1, "A": 6}
    5   {"A": 7, "D": -8}
    5   {"C": 13, "E": 5}
```

is there a package that can allow me to obtain a new data frame by splitting the client info into this format?

```
client   value   info
4        1       A
4        2       B
4        3       A
4        4       B
4        0       A
5        -1      C
5        6       A
5        7       A
5        -8      D
5        13      C
5        5       E
```

specifically is there anything in R that can read a dictionary like in python?

Comment: Please share your data with `dput()`. Also how did you convert the data into a `data.frame` in the first place?

Comment: data is read from a postgresql database

Comment: Instead of cleaning up the `data.frame`, it would make things a lot easier to properly parse the data right from the start. For example, you could read-in a PostgreSQL database using `dbplyr`.